# Sticky Footer not working with mobile responsive Off-Canvas Menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

I am using Bootstrap with a sticky footer and off-canvas menu. Sticky footer works fine on desktop view, but footer begins to overlap content on mobile view. I think it is due to the .row-offcanvas position being set to relative on mobile media query. If I remove the offcanvas menu the sticky footer works as expected on mobile devices. The other issue is when you scroll down in mobile view white space appears under the footer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="css/master-simple.css" rel="stylesheet">

      </head>

      <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

            <header>                           
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 headerLinks">
                    <a href="#" class="hidden-xs">Coverage Details</a>
                    <div id="drawerNavigationID" data-toggle="offcanvas" class="hidden-sm">
                      <span></span>
                      <span></span>
                      <span></span>
                    </div>              
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <a href="#" class="center-block"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-right headerLinks">
                    <!-- Click to call on Mobile Device -->
                    <a href="#" class="phoneIcon visible-xs"></a> 
                    <a href="#" class="hidden-xs">Contact Us</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </header>

            <!-- Off Canvas Menu -->
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 sidebar-offcanvas visible-xs">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="coverageDetails.html" title="Coverage Details">Coverage Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <div class="container mainWrapper">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-centered" id="confirmationWrapper">
                  <h2 class="noBorderBottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec laoreet tempor nisl, ut rutrum lacus vulputate vel.</h2>
                  <h3>CLAIM NUMBER: 12345678954</h3>
                  <p class="claimNumberText">Nulla libero enim, consequat at pulvinar eu, ultrices a risus.</p>
                  <p>Nulla libero enim, consequat at pulvinar eu, ultrices a risus. Mauris bibendum enim non magna maximus, non tempor lacus lacinia. Fusce vestibulum tincidunt vulputate. Suspendisse eu erat et neque facilisis consequat id in quam. Cras convallis massa at ornare hendrerit.</p>
                  <div class="row text-center">
                    <a href="#" target="blank" class="shopLink">Shop</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div><!-- End Page Content -->

            <footer>
              <div class="container">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p>&copy; 2015 ANulla libero enim</p>
              </div>
            </footer>

          </div><!-- End Container-fluid Row -->
        </div><!-- End Container-fluid -->

        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/offcanvas.js"></script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
            html {
              position: relative;
              min-height: 100%;
            }

            body {
              /* Margin bottom by footer height */
              margin-bottom: 196px;
            }

            * {
              font-weight: normal!important;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              outline: 0; 
              outline-style: none;
            }

            header {
              font-family: 'aig_futura_medregular', aig_futura_medregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
              position: absolute;
              top:0;
              z-index: 100;
              height: 92px;
              width: 100%;
              padding-top: 15px;
              color: #fff;
              background-color: rgba(0,164,228,0.9);
            }

            header a {
              font-family: "aig_futuraregular", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
              font-size: 18px;
              text-decoration: none;
              text-transform: uppercase;
              color: #fff!important;
            }

            header a:hover {
              border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
            }

            header .headerLogo {
              width: 116px;
              height: 63px;
              cursor: pointer;
              background: url(../img/aigLogo.png) no-repeat center bottom;
            }

            .headerLinks {
              margin-top: 20px;
            }

            footer {
              font-size: 14px;
              position: absolute;
              bottom: 0;
              width: 100%;
              /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
              height: 186px;
              padding: 40px 20px 20px;
              color: #fff;
              background-color: #252525;
            }

            footer ul {
              margin: 0 0 20px;
              padding: 0;
              list-style: none;
            }

            footer ul li {
              display: inline;
            }

            footer li a {
              color:#fff;
            }

            .mainWrapper {
              margin-top: 92px;
            }


            @media screen and (max-width:768px){    
               #drawerNavigationID{
                padding-left: 10px;
              }

              #drawerNavigationID span {
                display: block;
                width: 25px;
                height: 3px;
                background: #fff;
                margin-bottom: 7px;
              }

              .row-offcanvas {
                position: relative;
                bottom: 0;
                min-height: 100vh;
                -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
                     -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
                        transition: all .25s ease-out;
              }

              .row-offcanvas-left {
                left: 0;
              }

              .row-offcanvas-left .sidebar-offcanvas {
                left: -85%; 
                padding: 0 0 0 20px;
                background-color: #54565b;
              }

              .row-offcanvas-left .sidebar-offcanvas ul li {
                font-size: 18px;
                padding: 15px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #696b6f;
              }

              .row-offcanvas-left .sidebar-offcanvas a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #ffffff;
              }

              .row-offcanvas-left.active {
                left: 85%; 
              }

              .sidebar-offcanvas {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom:0;
                width: 85%; 
              }
            }
```

Comment: I would suggest only applying the sticky footer to the desktop (maybe tablet too). It is not really necessary in mobile websites in my opinion.